# Request Entity Too Large (App Engine + Docker + Java)

Tags: google-app-engine

I am aware that App Engine has a limit of 32 MB request upload limit. I am wondering if that could be increased.

A lot of other research suggests that I need to use the blobstore api directly, however my application has a special requirement where I cannot use it. 
Other issues suggest that you can modify the nginx file in your custom flex environment. However I ssh'd into the instance I did not see any nginx. I have a reason to believe that its the GAE Load Balancer blocking the request to even reach the application.

Here is my setup.

1. GAE Flex Environment
2. Custom Runtime, Java using Docker

Objective: I want to increase the client_max_body_size to a 100 MB.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/quotas#Blobstore) this limit is stated in the official documentation. There is no way you can increase that limit, as it is something regarding the  programming language itself. You can use Go environment, which has a limit of 64 MB.

This issue is discussed on more [forums](https://forum.opendatakit.org/t/google-appengine-limits-requests-to-a-max-size-of-32-mb/16606), but, for now, you just need to handle this kind of requests programatically. Check if they are bigger than 32MB, and in case they are, split them somehow and aggregate the results.

As a workaround you can also store the data in [Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/) as a temporary path for your workflow.